# Using Material Theme for API version 14 and above

Tags: android-appcompat, material-design

I read http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

I am using Android Studio 1.2 .
In my module's build.gradle file is the line
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'

I am still getting the error message that android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar
requires API 21.

What else do I need to do?

Comment: Use the themes inside the support library.

Comment: Which theme would be a direct replacement for Material?

Answer (score 0):

Use This

> Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

instead of

> Theme.Material.NoActionBar

Also Don't forget to include `appcompat-v7` in your project.